# simple expansion of rows in data.table by group IDs

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

For the following given dataset:

```
> df <- data.table(ID=LETTERS[1:4],y_min=c(1970,1973,1976,1971),y_max=c(1974,1975,1980,1974))
> df
   ID y_min y_max
1:  A  1970  1974
2:  B  1973  1975
3:  C  1976  1980
4:  D  1971  1974
```

ID represent a firm ID, and y_min and y_max are the first and last year that firm data appears in the dataset.

How can I expand the rows (by each firm) by creating a new column "year" that contains all the years in between the min and max years, so the following in produced:

```
> df
    ID y_min y_max year
 1:  A  1970  1974 1970
 2:  A  1970  1974 1971
 3:  A  1970  1974 1972
 4:  A  1970  1974 1973
 5:  A  1970  1974 1974
 6:  B  1973  1975 1973
 7:  B  1973  1975 1974
 8:  B  1973  1975 1975
 9:  C  1976  1980 1976
10:  C  1976  1980 1977
11:  C  1976  1980 1978
12:  C  1976  1980 1979
13:  C  1976  1980 1980
14:  D  1971  1974 1971
15:  D  1971  1974 1972
16:  D  1971  1974 1973
17:  D  1971  1974 1974
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to create a `list` column by grouping over the 'ID' column and then do the `:` between the 'y_min', 'y_max' and `unnest` (from `tidyr`) the `list` column

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
df[, year := .(list(y_min:y_max)), ID]
df %>%
    unnest(c(year))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 x 4
#   ID    y_min y_max  year
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 A      1970  1974  1970
# 2 A      1970  1974  1971
# 3 A      1970  1974  1972
# 4 A      1970  1974  1973
# 5 A      1970  1974  1974
# 6 B      1973  1975  1973
# 7 B      1973  1975  1974
# 8 B      1973  1975  1975
# 9 C      1976  1980  1976
#10 C      1976  1980  1977
#11 C      1976  1980  1978
#12 C      1976  1980  1979
#13 C      1976  1980  1980
#14 D      1971  1974  1971
#15 D      1971  1974  1972
#16 D      1971  1974  1973
#17 D      1971  1974  1974
```

---

Or using only `data.table`

```
df[, year := Map(`:`, y_min, y_max)]
df[rep(seq_len(.N), lengths(year))][, year := unlist(df$year)][]
```

-output

```
#     ID y_min y_max year
# 1:  A  1970  1974 1970
# 2:  A  1970  1974 1971
# 3:  A  1970  1974 1972
# 4:  A  1970  1974 1973
# 5:  A  1970  1974 1974
# 6:  B  1973  1975 1973
# 7:  B  1973  1975 1974
# 8:  B  1973  1975 1975
# 9:  C  1976  1980 1976
#10:  C  1976  1980 1977
#11:  C  1976  1980 1978
#12:  C  1976  1980 1979
#13:  C  1976  1980 1980
#14:  D  1971  1974 1971
#15:  D  1971  1974 1972
#16:  D  1971  1974 1973
#17:  D  1971  1974 1974
```

---

Or with a self-join

```
df[df, .(y_min, y_max, year = y_min:y_max), on = .(ID), by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think there's a purely data.table solution possible, maybe by using CJ?

Comment: @lovestacksflow updated the post with a data.table solution